# Where can I find labeled sentences?

Tags: data-request, nlp, text

I am looking for sentences csv labeled like this, or something similar:

```
I am going to run a marathon., achievement
I miss my high school friend., friendship
I would like to lose 10 pounds, achievement
```

Are there any resources that have labelled data like this?

Comment: If it proves too difficult to find a properly labelled dataset, I wonder how well something like tweets labelled by hashtags would work for your case.

Comment: I took some time to look at Twitter hash tags after your suggestion. However, I don't think it is accurate enough for what I am looking for.